# add the count of doc in list inside python code to a field in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, update-by-query

I need to update a field of a doc in Elasticsearch and add the count of that doc in a list inside python code. The `weight` field contains the count of the doc in a dataset. The dataset needs to be updated from time to time.So the count of each document must be updated too. `hashed_ids` is a list of document ids that are in the new batch of data. the `weight` of matched id must be increased by the count of that id in `hashed_ids`.
I tried the code below but it does not work.

```
hashed_ids = [hashlib.md5(doc.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() for doc in shingles]
update_with_query_body = {
        "script": {
            "source": "ctx._source.content_completion.weight +=param.count",
            "lang": "painless",
            "param": {
                "count": hashed_ids.count("ctx.['_id']")
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "ids": {
                "values": hashed_ids
            }
        }
    }
```

for example let say a doc with `id`=`d1b145716ce1b04ea53d1ede9875e05a` and `weight`=5 is already present in index. and also the string `d1b145716ce1b04ea53d1ede9875e05a` is repeated three times in the `hashed_ids` so the `update_with_query` query shown above will match the doc in database. I need to add 3 to 5 and have 8 as final `weight`

Comment: can you explain in a bit more detail of what you want to do?

Comment: @gaurav9620 I updated the question with more explanation

Comment: You want to update a field in the document and add the count to a data structure in python code. Isn't? If so, can you add a sample how it should be?

Comment: @Gibbs I added some more explanations

Comment: So, `hashed_ids` is an [array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) type and if it matches with it's own `id` then you need to update `weight` of the same document. So all three are related to same document fields. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Gibbs yes,you are absolutely correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of python but here is an e.g. based solution with a few assumptions.
Let's say the following is the `hashed_ids` extracted:

```
hashed_ids = ["id1","id1","id1","id2"]
```

To use it in terms query we can get just the unique list of ids, i.e.

```
hashed_ids_unique = ["id1", "id2"]
```

Lets assume the doc(s) are indexed with below structure:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "id": "id1",
  "weight":9
}
```

Now we can use update by query as below:

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "query":{
    "terms": {
      "id":["id1","id2"]
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "source":"long weightToAdd = params.hashed_ids.stream().filter(idFromList -> ctx._source.id.equals(idFromList)).count(); ctx._source.weight += weightToAdd;",
    "params":{
      "hashed_ids":["id1","id1","id1","id2"]
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation for script:

The following gives the count of matching ids in the `hashed_ids` list for the `id` of the current matching doc.

```
long weightToAdd = params.hashed_ids.stream().filter(idFromList -> ctx._source.id.equals(idFromList)).count();
```

The following adds up the `weightToAdd` to the existing value of `weight` in the document.

```
ctx._source.weight += weightToAdd;
```